# How to make the div append as Popup rather than text

Tags: jquery

when clcked on a popup button , i need to show the similar behaviour as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/31/

I was trying the same as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/32/

But rather than popup its being appended as a text content

Scenario :

Click on the Heading 1 Or Heading 2 (Labels) and then click on close button

This is what i was trying

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(event) {

    var html = '<div data-role="popup" id="transitionExample" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">\
                <div class="popup_inner popup_sm">\n\
                    <div class="popup_content popup_myactivelabels_content">\n\
                        <p>Sorry! Now we are not able to delivery these timings</p>\n\
                        <h3>Our Available timings</h3>\n\
                        <p>11am to 2pm</p>\n\
                    </div>\n\
                    <div class="popup_footer">\n\
                        <a>Ok, Got It.</a>\n\
                    </div>\n\
                </div>\n\
            </div>'


    $(this).closest('.labellistUL').append(html);
});
```

could you please tell me how to behave as same as present in the first fiddle

Comment: I resolved it this way , $(document).on('click', '.close', function(event) {
  

$('#transitionExample').popup('open')    
    
});  http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/35/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve it like this as well. You don't need to bind click events if you do it this way. Just copy paste to your fiddle and remove your bind events.

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                <h3>Heading 1<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3>

            <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">        
                <li class="labellist">
                    <div class="close"> <a href="#transitionExample" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline closestyle" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Position to window</a>

                    </div>
                </li>    </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                <h3>Heading 2<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3>

            <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">        
                <li class="labellist">
                    <div class="close">
                        <a href="#transitionExample" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline closestyle" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Position to window</a>
                    </div>
                </li>    </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExample" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="popup_inner popup_sm">
            <div class="popup_content popup_myactivelabels_content">
                <p>Sorry! Now we are not able to delivery these timings</p>
                    <h3>Our Available timings</h3>

                <p>11am to 2pm</p>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_footer">  <a>Ok, Got It.</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```